# Sending each elements of a list as parameters of function

Tags: python, list, function, parameters, element

How to send each list element as a function parameter in python?

```
list1 = ['38', '39', '40', ...]
any_function(list_item)
```

I can't know that length of the list that's why i can't send every element of the list as a function's parameter at the same time.
Is there any Pythonic way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your function parameter to e.g. `*args`:

```
list1 = ['38', '39', '40']

def printemall(*args):
    print(args)

printemall(list1)
# (['38', '39', '40'],)

printemall(*list1)
# ('38', '39', '40')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def any_function(item):
    print(item)

def calling_function():
    list1 = ['38','39', '40']
    for item in list1:
        any_function(item)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: No, that's not the answer i want.What i want is passing each element of a list at the same time.